# How to remove indentation for all paragraphs?

Tags: indentation

I am finding this very inefficient, every time I type up something MiKTeX just indents for me and I have to enclose everything in `\noindent{...}`.

Is there a quick way of going past this?

Comment: `\noindent` is a switch, not a macro that takes an argument. Therefore, you don't need the braces.

Comment: I do...if I don't the next sentence in my document just keeps indenting without my permission.

Comment: Maybe indentation helps recognising the paragraphs?

Comment: Of course normally typeset text has paragraph indent. What kind of text is it that you are writing where you don't want paragraph indentation? Maybe the real solution is that you use a document class that is meant for the type of text you are writing.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you don't want any indent, anywhere in your document, add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` in your document preamble. This quick-fix works, but it is better to include the [`parskip` package](//ctan.org/pkg/parskip). It manages the two lengths `\parskip` and `\parindent` together:

```
\usepackage{parskip}% http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip
```

From [the `parskip` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/parskip):

> Package to be used with any document class at any size. It produces
> the following Paragraph Layout:

> Zero `\parindent` and non-zero `\parskip`. The stretchable
> glue in `\parskip` helps LaTeX in finding the best place for
> page breaks.

> In addition, the package adjusts the skips between list items.
> With package option `parfill`, the package also adjusts `\parfillskip`
> to impose a minimum space at the end of the last line of a paragraph.

[`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and [`KOMA-script`](//ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes provide similar functionality.

Comment: I am new to this game, so \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} works!

Comment: @jak Especially  because you are new to this game, you should use Werner's second solution.  Use the `parskip` package, instead of just changing the `\parindent` length.

Comment: But I don't understand what the package's difference makes

Comment: @jak: The [`parskip` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) does more than just `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`. It also maintains other lengths that "interact with `\parindent`" (like lists).

Comment: @jak: "Changing `\parindent` and `\parskip` is considered as one
of the deadly sins", as per [Too much white space before enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14764/too-much-whitespace-before-enumerate).

Comment: @PeterGrill it appears you refer to [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14768/49424), but it seems the answerer misinterpreted [his reference](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english), see also [my comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14764/too-much-whitespace-before-lists-when-changing-the-parskip-length#comment686285_14768).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom: I don't know if jak deleted his comment or if Hawk previously went by the username jak?

Comment: @PeterGrill It seems Hawk went by the jak, because he was to referred to as jak [in another comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40351/horizontal-line-not-working#comment81875_40356)

Comment: @PeterGrill it seems the reference I mention above is against the combination of `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` and
`\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}`, because of the side effects of `\parskip`. It seems `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` in isolation is harmless. If you know more, I would like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom: Sorry, I don't know any more than that reference. I would suggest you post a question and reference Gonzalo Medina's answer that mentions it.

Comment: `\usepackage{parskip}` adds vertical spacing between elements throughout the document. `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` solves it without side-effects.

Comment: @qubodup: As mentioned, [`parskip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) adds "..non-zero `\parskip`. The stretchable glue in `\parskip` helps LaTeX in finding the best place for page breaks." If you're using something like `\raggedbottom` in your document, go with `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}`, otherwise (with something like `\flushbottom`) you might run into underful `\vbox` issues.

Comment: `parskip` causes some weird behavior in some cases. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446195/parskip-package-causing-some-problems-in-parbox-itemize-content

Comment: It doesn't remove the indentation for my situation together with tufte-handout style.

Comment: LaTeX needs a package in order to set `\parindent=0pt`? :).