# parskip package causing some problems in parbox itemize content

Tags: parskip

Here is some simplified content to describe my problem

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}


\begin{document}

Some notational items:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Infinite series are referred to only as series.
    \item Dropping the index and infinity symbol from the summation symbol is also possible. i.e $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum a_n$. It also implies starting point of the series is not important. It can begin with $0$, $1$, $3$ or any other number...
    \item Not dropping the index from the summation symbol will occur when the index really does need to be there and cannot be changed

\end{itemize}

\fbox{
\parbox{\textwidth}{
If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent series then:

\begin{itemize}
    \item sadsads
    \item sdafsdf
\end{itemize}
}
}

\end{document}
```

I would like to box the contents of the `\parbox`, but I have realized that the spacing between the text after each bullet, and the spacing between normal text and bulleted lists is different for stuff inside `\parbox` than it is for stuff outside.

One way to rid myself of this problem is to **not** import the `parskip` package. So I know importing it is what causes the weird re-spacing inside the `\parbox`. However I need to import `parskip` for other reasons, namely because I don't want to indent my paragraphs in this particular document.

How can I prevent this behavior, and keep my paragraphs non-indented? Perhaps there is a way without importing `parskip`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\parbox` automatically resets the `parskip` to `0pt`.
If you do not want this, you can patch the internal macro to avoid changing `\parskip` using `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{parskip}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@arrayparboxrestore{\parskip}{\@gobble}{}{\undefined}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some notational items:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Infinite series are referred to only as series.
    \item Dropping the index and infinity symbol from the summation symbol is also possible. i.e $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum a_n$. It also implies starting point of the series is not important. It can begin with $0$, $1$, $3$ or any other number...
    \item Not dropping the index from the summation symbol will occur when the index really does need to be there and cannot be changed
\end{itemize}

\fbox{
\parbox{\textwidth}{
If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent series then:

\begin{itemize}
    \item sadsads
    \item sdafsdf
\end{itemize}
}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There does not exist a more economical way of doing this? By economical I mean a solution which keeps the same number of imported packages or reduces the number of imported packages?

Comment: @user32882 You can let `\parbox` set `\parskip` to zero and reset it afterwards, see the answer from Steven B. Segletes.

Answer (score 3):

Change some code in the package to restore the `\parskip` inside the list.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\makeatletter

\edef\svparskip{\the\parskip}
\def\@listI{\parskip=\svparskip\relax\leftmargin\leftmargini
   \topsep\z@ \parsep\parskip \itemsep\z@}
\let\@listi\@listI
\@listi

\makeatother
\begin{document}

Some notational items:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Infinite series are referred to only as series.
    \item Dropping the index and infinity symbol from the summation symbol is also possible. i.e $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum a_n$. It also implies starting point of the series is not important. It can begin with $0$, $1$, $3$ or any other number...
    \item Not dropping the index from the summation symbol will occur when the index really does need to be there and cannot be changed

\end{itemize}

\fbox{
\parbox{\textwidth}{
If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent series then:

\begin{itemize}
    \item sadsads
    \item sdafsdf
\end{itemize}
}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]