# Text is not aligned left after table/pagebreak?

Tags: tables, page-breaking

the table in my essay is followed by a pagebreak (as shown in the example), however, the {Heading} (text) is not properly left aligned. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,

```
\pagebreak 
\sffamily \large \textbf{test} % this is the problem, here the text is not as left aligned to the left side of the page as it should be; further information: before the \pagebreak is another table 
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\sffamily
\small
\begin{longtable}{p{15cm}}
\caption{tets }\\[2ex]
\hline 
\textcolor{black}{test)} \\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{test}} \\
\hline
\small test\\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{test}} \\ 
\hline
\small test \\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{C}} \\
\hline
\small test \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
}
```

Comment: it is not really a heading, you are right just a paragraph; the problem is that it is a bit too far right and does not alight where it should be (left to the side)

Comment: You need to provide an example of the problem, but as I say it will be indented (by around 15pt normally) as it is a paragraph start.

Comment: I edited the information and but down the structure of the table

Comment: `test` is the start of a paragraph so (depending on code you have not shown)  will be indented by paragraph indent. you could use `\noindent` to suppress that but noindent should never be used, the paragraph indention (or lack of it)  should be set up as a global style in the document preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global setting for zero indent added in preamble

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

the **output**::

[image]
**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
% \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
% \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%<______for zero indent in the whole document set to zero
% \setlength{\parindent}{1in}%<_________indent length variation can be set before 
                            %the paragraph or for the whole document
\begin{document} 
\pagebreak 
\sffamily \large \textbf{test} % this is the problem, here the text is not as left aligned to the left side of the page as it should be; further information: before the \pagebreak is another table 
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\sffamily
\small
\begin{longtable}{p{15cm}}
\caption{tets }\\[2ex]
\hline 
\textcolor{black}{test)} \\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{test}} \\
\hline
\small test\\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{test}} \\ 
\hline
\small test \\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{C}} \\
\hline
\small test \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

The indentation can be changed midway in the document by adding

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1in}
```

and the **output** with above 1 inch setting::

[image]

**PS**

Do read the following while using the \parindent command --- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55016/197451

**EDIT**

```
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\begin{verbatim}  
    % how to set font size here to 10 px ?  
\end{verbatim}
```

The first parameter to fontsize is the font size to switch to and the second is the line spacing to use

Comment: thanks, I am not sure whether it had something to do with that (I don't think so) but suddenly, the font of my appendix is totally different from the rest of my paper. Do you know maybe how to solve that?

Comment: see edit above and let me know

Comment: Also I just noticed that I can't use the global par indent you suggested as it remove my indentations within the document.

Comment: then you need to use it selectively -- see remarks above --- The indentation can be changed midway in the document by adding

`\setlength{\parindent}{1in}`

Comment: \setlength{\parindent}{0in} - thanks it worked! Now just gotta solve the problem with the font

Comment: pls see edit above for font

Comment: it did not work your suggestion with the font. Even if I change my "times" font back to the latex one, the last few pages just don't change font - it is like it is suck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104858/discussion-between-js-bibra-and-karl-l).

Answer (score 0):

If the start of a single paragraph should not be indented use `\noindent` in front of it:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1]

\pagebreak

\noindent% <- avoids the \parindent
{\sffamily \large \textbf{test}\par}% <- changed to limit the font change
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\sffamily
\small
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}
\caption{tets }\\[2ex]
\hline 
\textcolor{black}{test)} \\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{test}} \\
\hline
\small test\\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{test}} \\ 
\hline
\small test \\
\hline
\textcolor{black}{\textbf{C}} \\
\hline
\small test \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```