# How to remove indentation from one section?

Tags: indentation

I don't want indentation in my appendix. I can use `\noindent` for every single paragraph, but is there an easier way?

I do want indentation in other sections of my document, so I can't use the solutions proposed in

- [How to remove indentation for all paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55015/how-to-remove-indentation-for-all-paragraphs)
- [How to disable automatic indentation on new paragraphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14375/how-to-disable-automatic-indentation-on-new-paragraphs)
- [Is there an easy way to have my whole document with a space between paragraphs rather than indentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42/is-there-an-easy-way-to-have-my-whole-document-with-a-space-between-paragraphs-r)

How can I remove indentation on **every paragraph** in a single section?

Comment: \parindent=0pt will do it (from that point until reset).  Or \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

Comment: @JohnKormylo That works for me. Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.